# Why can't I add most plugins under Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: qgis, plugins, ubuntu

I loaded QGIS into 12.04 with much trouble but it works. Although I do not seem to be able to load most plugins.  I go to fetch plugins and most are not loaded so I try to load some and they will not load including many that I used with 11.10.  I click on fetch and then plugins and then highlight a plugin and like Table Manager and click Install Plugin and the box appears:

Failed to unzip the plugin package. Probably it's broken or missing from the repository. You may also want to make sure that you have write permission to the plugin directory:
/home/hebert/.qgis//python/plugins

This is true for 90% of the plugins.  Help!

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using on 12.04?

Answer (score 7):

You just need to give yourself ownership of the the /.qgis directory where the plugins will be install. Use the change owner command in the terminal:

```
sudo chown "your username" ~/.qgis
```

You may also need to make the chown command recursive to cover the folders and files within the ~/.qgis folder:

```
sudo chown -R "your username" ~/.qgis
```

Comment: sudo chown "your username" ./.qgis It works to me. So simple. Amazing!

Comment: First, it should be `~/.qgis`, since it is in the user's home dir, not in the arbitrary current dir. Secondly, something bad would have to happen for the same user to lose ownership there in the first place (other worries).

Answer (score 6):

I installed QGis 1.9 with adding repositories to source list:

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main

deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main
```

And public key:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 1F9ADD375CA44993

gpg --export --armor 1F9ADD375CA44993 | sudo apt-key add -
```

So far works fine and no problems with getting plugins.

Comment: how do you add the public key?  With the Terminal?

Comment: Hei! Yes, in the Terminal. Just copy-paste the Public key lines (mentioned in post just above) and hit Enter. Then add the Repositories to your source list using _sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list_ . Save the file. After that hit in the Terminal _sudo apt-get update_ and _sudo apt-get install qgis_ and You got QGIs.

Answer (score 3):

It seems QGIS is removed from Debian and Ubuntu Precise repositories:

- [Ubuntu-Package-Search: QGIS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qgis)
- [UbuntuUpdates Info about QGIS](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/qgis)
- [Debian Bug Report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=662195)

The PPAs from UbuntuGis do not provide packages for Ubuntu Precise at the moment:

- [ubuntugis](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa/)
- [ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable)

**Update:**
ubuntugis-unstable starts providing a`QGIS` package for Ubuntu Precise..

Comment: What do I do?  Re-install Qgis when the packages are available or wait for updates and updates will fix it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

OP said they couldn't install 90% of plugins - I found, after upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04, that only the core plugins (C++?) were available, to get all the python plug-ins as well, you need to install the package python-qgis as well.

I wonder if that's what the OP meant.  After installing python-qgis the full list of plugins reappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind to change ownership for QGIS 2.0 with this command:

```
sudo chown -R "your username" ~/.qgis2
```